# IDisposable pattern, is SafeFileHandle an unmanaged resource?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, idisposable

Take the following snippet of `IDisposable` pattern generated by Resharper:

```
[NotNull]
private SafeFileHandle Handle { get; }

#region IDisposable

private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
{
    // TODO release unmanaged resources here
}

private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (IsDisposed)
        return;

    ReleaseUnmanagedResources();

    if (disposing)
        Handle.Dispose();

    IsDisposed = true;
}

~Whatever()
{
    Dispose(false);
}
```

Resharper considers `SafeFileHandle` as a managed resource, but this handle is about an unmanaged resource (`CreateFile`).

**Question:**

Should a `SafeFileHandle` be considered a managed or unmanaged resource when disposing it?

Comment: It's managed -- it's a C# type which wraps an unmanaged resource, and it defines its own finalizer, which releases that unmanaged resource if necessary. Typically unmanaged resources will be pointed to by an `IntPtr`, or some other custom type you declared for use in p/invoke

Comment: It should be considered as managed resource. Take a look at this good article: https://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/safehandle/

Comment: Thank you guys, feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All C# classes and structs are managed resources<sup>1</sup>.

Unmanaged resources are typically pointed to by an `IntPtr`, or something similar. You normally need to do something very deliberate to get your hands on one (such as P/Invoking some native method, or using one of the methods on `Marshal`).

`SafeFileHandle` is a subclass of `SafeHandle`, which is a type specifically made to wrap unmanaged resources. `SafeHandle` defines its own finalizer, which releases the unmanaged resource in a suitable way if necessary.

---

It's good advice to *never* own your own unmanaged resources, and instead *always* use a `SafeHandle` / `CriticalFinalizerObject` subclass to manage them.

This avoids one of the big P/Invoke pitfalls, and also means you don't have to implement the full `IDisposable` pattern in your code: you only need to define a `Dispose()` method which calls `Dispose()` on your `SafeHandles`, and don't need to implement a finalizer.

(Some people may need to deviate from this for performance reasons, but those people are few and far between)

---

<sup>1</sup>Generic types with an `unmanaged` constraint aside...